# Calendar usage limits exceeded adding attendee to an event

Tags: event-handling, jwt, google-calendar-api

I'm testing Google Calendar API with service account and JWT authentication server to server.
All runs fine except when I try to create an event inside a calendar I receive the error
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
The problem appears only when I add an attendee to the event.
If I try to create the same event in the same calendar without any attendee, al works fine.

I receive the same error if I try to add the attendee in a second moment after event creation.

So, at this time, I cannot invite any person to any event programmatically.
For me this is a very big problem.

Can you help me?

Thanks!

EDIT:
I'm using ApiRest with ServiceAccount and JWT token.
This is a sample running fine:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{{calendarId}}/events?access_token={{access_token}}
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-01-17T14:50:05Z"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-01-17T13:50:05Z"
  },
  "summary": "prova",
}
```

while this one returns error

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/{{calendarId}}/events?access_token={{access_token}}
{
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2020-01-17T14:50:05Z"
  },
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2020-01-17T13:50:05Z"
  },
  "attendees":[{"email":"xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"}],
  "summary": "prova",
}
```

returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "domain": "usageLimits",
                "reason": "quotaExceeded",
                "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
            }
        ],
        "code": 403,
        "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."
    }
}
```

There is no difference between POST and PUT method that implements respectively event creation and event update.
When I add any attendee, the result is always error.

Comment: The issue is happening when you create a new event or when you are modifying an old one? What programming language are you using? Could you please provide in your question the request body you built to see if there is an error there?

Comment: It's working as intended for me, have you tried using the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert?apix_params=%7B%22calendarId%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22end%22%3A%7B%22dateTime%22%3A%222020-01-22T14%3A50%3A05Z%22%7D%2C%22start%22%3A%7B%22dateTime%22%3A%222020-01-17T13%3A50%3A05Z%22%7D%2C%22summary%22%3A%22Attendees%20test%22%2C%22attendees%22%3A%5B%7B%22email%22%3A%22user%40domain%22%7D%5D%7D%7D) for testing purposes? What programming language are you using? Probably it's an error in your logic

Comment: I'm calling REST API directly by POSTMAN or cURL. Are you sure that you're calling API like me? Are you trying with service account and JWT authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Searching about your issue I found out it's been a well-known problem for a while and it's been reported on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) in these threads:

- [Service account is unable to invite calendar groups to calendar events](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141704931)
- [Unable to set reminders via API request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141903683)
- [Can't send notification through service account calendar](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/140746812)